# Find array indices

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sure there is a CS term for what I'm trying to accomplish but I'm not sure what it is. I have three arrays, let's call them `a`, `b`, and `c`.  I am iterating through every possible combination of the arrays, which would be `a*b*c` iterations.

I am passing a function an `int` of the current iteration  (such that `iteration` goes from `0` to  `a*b*c-1`) and the length of `a`, `b`, and `c`. I want that function to be able to print out every unique permutation of indices, calculated from just the iteration count and the lengths of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

This is what I have now:

```
class Test {
    public static void printIndices(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
        System.out.println(i%a + ", " + (i+1)%b + ", " + (i+2)%c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[2];
        int b[] = new int[2];
        int c[] = new int[3];

        int iterations = a.length * b.length * c.length;

        for (int i=0; i < iterations; i++){
            printIndices(i, a.length, b.length, c.length);
        }
    }
}
```

It generates this output:

```
0, 1, 2
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 1
1, 0, 2
0, 1, 0
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 2
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 1
1, 0, 2
0, 1, 0
1, 0, 1
```

As you can see there are duplicates.  I want the output to be:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
1, 1, 0
0, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
0, 0, 2
1, 0, 2
0, 1, 2
1, 1, 2
```

(the order is unimportant, as long as every permutation is there with no duplicates).

Obviously my output line is wrong:

```
System.out.println(i%a + ", " + (i+1)%b + ", " + (i+2)%c);
```

What are the correct operations to get the output I am looking for?

I understand that this code is a bit silly looking and it's not at all what I'm actually doing, but it demonstrates the case well.

Comment: This is called a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: Thanks. I knew there must be some term for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are looking for the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Your approach with modular arithmetic almost works. You need only a few modifications to get the correct result:

```
System.out.println(i%a + ", " + (i/a)%b + ", " + (i/a/b)%c);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/nPFXu)